# Kendo Grid AJAX Bound Not Updating MVC4

Tags: asp.net, ajax, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to get my grid to update for the opt-in status, but when I hit update no action occurs. I an using ajax binding with a model and entity framework.  When I hit cancel it will follow this method. I am not sure what I am missing as everything else functions and compiles.

View

```
<div class="row">
<h2>PQA Opt-In</h2>

<br />

 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<TelerikMvcApp1.Models.PQAViewModel>()
    .Name("grid")
     .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(opt => opt.Jobber).Width(90);
        columns.Bound(opt => opt.Dealer).Width(95);
        columns.Bound(opt => opt.OptInd).Width(110);
        columns.Bound(opt => opt.establish_date_time);
        columns.Bound(opt => opt.establish_id);
        columns.Command(commands =>
            {
                commands.Edit();
            }).Title("Commands").Width(200); 
       })
            .DataSource(datasource => datasource
                .Ajax()
                .Model(model =>
                    {
                        model.Id(opt => opt.Jobber);
                        model.Field(opt => opt.Jobber).Editable(false); 
                        model.Field(opt => opt.Dealer).Editable(false);
                        model.Field(opt => opt.establish_date_time).Editable(false);
                        model.Field(opt => opt.establish_id).Editable(false);
                    })
                .PageSize(20)
                .Read(read => read.Action("ProductQualityFileFull_Read", "PQA"))
                .Update(update => update.Action("Opt_Update", "PQA"))
              )
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
   .Filterable()
    .Pageable() 
 )  



  </div>
```

Controller

```
sing System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Data; 
using System.Data.Entity; 
using TelerikMvcApp1.Models;
using Kendo.Mvc.UI;
using Kendo.Mvc.Extensions;

 namespace TelerikMvcApp1.Controllers
{
public class PQAController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Baseline()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult ProductQualityFileFull_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest  
 request)
    {
        using (var pqa = new PQAEntities())
        {
            IQueryable<ProductQualityFileFull> opt = pqa.ProductQualityFileFulls;
            DataSourceResult result = opt.ToDataSourceResult(request, ProductQualityFileFull => 
new PQAViewModel
            {
                Jobber = ProductQualityFileFull.Jobber,
                Dealer = ProductQualityFileFull.Dealer,
                OptInd = ProductQualityFileFull.OptInd,
                establish_date_time = ProductQualityFileFull.establish_date_time,
                establish_id = ProductQualityFileFull.establish_id

            });
            return Json(result);
        }
    }

    public ActionResult UpdateOptIn()
    {

        return View();

    }



    public ActionResult Opt_Update([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, 
PQAViewModel opt)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (var pqa = new PQAEntities())
            {
                var entity = new ProductQualityFileFull
            {
                Jobber = opt.Jobber,
                Dealer = opt.Dealer,
                OptInd = opt.OptInd,
                establish_date_time = opt.establish_date_time,
                establish_id = opt.establish_id
            };

                pqa.ProductQualityFileFulls.Attach(entity);

                pqa.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;

                pqa.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        return Json(new[] { opt }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));

    }
  }
}
```

Model

```
namespace TelerikMvcApp1.Models
{
 public class PQAViewModel
 {
    public string Jobber { get; set; }
    public int Dealer { get; set; }
    public int OptInd { get; set; }
    public DateTime establish_date_time { get; set; }
    public string establish_id { get; set; }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have made all your columns non-editable - which means you will not make any changed to the model. And if no change is made - no update request is performed. Make a change to your model and the update should be triggered.

Comment: I only made certain field non-editable. The OptInd is editable, and I did not include it in the m odel. I added it to the model and set it as .Editable(true) and the update still did not work.